# Why Strava API's segment_efforts always returns empty result?

Tags: strava

I'm trying to get a list of efforts through Strava API, I created my app, went to https://developers.strava.com/playground/#/ and followed the Autorization procedure.

Everything is setup correctly as when I run `GET /athletes` I see my personal information as respond.

Also, when I run `GET /segments/14516262` I get my segment's description as respond.

However, when I run `GET /segment_efforts?segment_id=23430539&start_date_local=2019-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%2B01%3A00&end_date_local=2021-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%2B01%3A00&per_page=30`, the result I get is `[]` while I ride this segments many times in 2019 and 2020.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On May 18th, 2020 Strava applied [changes to the Segments API](https://developers.strava.com/docs/segment-changes/).

Segment Leaderboard endpoint is **not available**:

- `/api/v3/segments/:id/leaderboard`

Segment efforts are **only available for subscribers** in the following endpoints:

- `/api/v3/segments/:id`
- `/api/v3/segment_efforts`
- `/api/v3/segment_efforts/:id/streams`
- `api/v3/activities/:id`

For 30 days the affected endpoints will return empty data for free users, except for the Segment Leaderboard endpoint which will return empty data for all users. After June 18th, they will all either omit the data or return an error message.

Please note that at the end of the document there is this info: *"Individual segment efforts, segment efforts within activities, personal achievements (PRs) and top 10 leaderboard rankings are still available regardless of subscription status."*

I think this document isn't very clear but, as a free user, I'm still able to use:

- `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/{id}?include_all_efforts=true`
- `/api/v3/segments/:id/leaderboard`

Something is different from the past; for example, the leaderboard API still works but returns a different set of data and some parameters disappeared.

Doing some tests with Postman it seems that:

- `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segment_efforts?segment_id=<segment_id>` always return `[]`
- `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/<segment_id>` now contains `athlete_segment_stats` section with your personal record (I don't remember this section prior changes but maybe I'm wrong)
- `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segment_efforts/<segmenteffort_id>` still works

I don't know exactly what you need but maybe you can:

1. get your activities in a certain period
2. get segment efforts of a singular activity
3. analyze segment effort

Comment: Hi tezzo. Thanks for your help. I'm trying to retrieve my list of efforts for a given segment (basically what used to be displayed as "Your Recent Efforts"), I have a free account and would like this feature back...;-). I can't get `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/{id}?include_all_efforts=true` working, it reports "Resource Not Found", do you confirm activiy id can be retrieved from a strava page `https://www.strava.com/activities/{id}/overview`? Also, if I want to use `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segment_efforts/<segmenteffort_id>`, where should I get the `<segmenteffort_id>` from?

Comment: I could make `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segment_efforts/<segmenteffort_id>` work from a `<segmenteffort_id>` I got from the website by expanding a segment in an activity (`https://www.strava.com/activities/{activity_id}/segments/{segmenteffort_id}`). Now, the only thing missing is a way to get all my `{segmenteffort_id}` from a given segment...but if they disabled `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segment_efforts?segment_id=<segment_id>` that's maybe not possible anymore...

Comment: you can't get all your efforts from a given segments but using https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-getActivityById (tested now, it still works) you are able to get all the efforts of a run/ride and filter by a segment id if necessary. you can get activity id from `https://www.strava.com/activities/{id}` or get all your activities using https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-getLoggedInAthleteActivities